# fill input if radio is selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input and two radio buttons.

The input accepts a number for a time period a person lives at a residence.

The radio buttons are months & years.

I want to fill a 2nd input using the 1st input value (numerical value of length at residence) and either the value for months or years based on the radio selected.

I've made it spit out the time, but it spits out the value for both radio button because I did not have an if statement to check.  I already have jquery in my form and it works.  I just need this small section of my form to work.

My question is, how do I set up the conditional statement for checking what radio is checked?

HTML

```
<input type="number" value="" required maxlength="5" class="form-control" name="homeLength" id="homeLength">
<input type="radio" id="years" value="Years" name="length" required> Years
<input type="radio" id="months" value="Months" name="length"> Months
```

jQuery

```
$('#months').click(function () {
  if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
    $('#homeLength, #months').bind('keypress blur', function () {
      $('#homeTime').val($('#homeLength').val() + ' ' + ' ' + $('#months').val() + ' ' + ' ');
    });
  }
});

$('#years').click(function () {
  if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
    $('#homeLength, #years').bind('keypress blur', function () {
      $('#homeTime').val($('#homeLength').val() + ' ' + ' ' + $('#years').val() + ' ');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is `<... id="hometime"...>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replave your javascript code with this

```
  $('#months').click(function() {
      console.log($(this).prop('id'));
      $('#homeLength, #months').bind('keypress blur', function() {
        $('#homeTime').val($('#homeLength').val() + ' ' + ' '+$('#months').val()+ ' ' + ' ');
      }); 
  });
  $('#years').click(function() {
      console.log($(this).prop('id'));
      $('#homeLength, #years').bind('keypress blur', function() {
        $('#homeTime').val($('#homeLength').val() + ' ' + ' ' + $('#years').val()+ ' ');
      }); 
  });
```

whenever user will select any radio button u can get its id by

```
$(this).prop('id');
```

its value by

```
$(this).prop('value');
```

Comment: No need to check a radio is checked since clicking on it checks it

Comment: Yes you are right but accourding to his code i haven't changed much. So he can easily understand

Comment: Thanks, this worked to perfection.  I appreciate it.

Comment: No it does not. It is poor programming to leave in unnecessary event handlers and deprecated methods.

Comment: yes you are right its useless i have added checked condition

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the checked radio's value only and do that on keyup/blur AND click of any radio

```js
$(function() {
  $('#homeLength').on('keyup, blur', function() {
    var lgt = $("input:radio[name=length]:checked").val();
    $('#homeTime').val($(this).val() + ' '+lgt);
  });
  $("input:radio[name=length]").on("click",function() { 
    $('#homeLength').blur(); // trigger the blur event of the field to update
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="" required maxlength="5" class="form-control" name="homeLength" id="homeLength">
<input type="radio" id="years" value="Years" name="length" required> Years
<input type="radio" id="months" value="Months" name="length"> Months
<hr/>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="homeTime" id="homeTime">
```

Answer (score 1):

The most usable conditional statement for this kind of checkings is:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

so as you can see the response is boolean.